Selenium-wire not authenticating proxy when used with user data directory
I want to use Selenium-wire to see the requests that are being made to a site with a session. The sessions are coming from a user data directory, which were previously created with seleniumbase and a proxy. The issue is that the user data directory has the proxy attached to it, and selenium-wire can't authenticate the proxy for some reason. It brings up a pop-up that says "The proxy XXX:XXX requires a username and password".
I have the original proxies saved, with their usernames and passwords. When I manually input the username and password, it works perfectly and the session is valid.
Here is a snippet of the code:
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://{user}:{pw}@{ip}:{host}',
        'https': f'https://{user}:{pw}@{ip}:{host}',
    }
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={userDataDir}")

sb = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)

sb.set_window_position(10, 10)
sb.set_window_size(640, 750)

sb.get("site-here")
for request in sb.requests:
    print(request)


exit = input("press enter to exit")
sb.quit()

I don't know why it isn't authenticating properly. The credentials work and the proxies work as well. This is happening for every saved session I have.
I expected the site to open and the proxy to be valid, as well as the session to be valid. If I remove the user data directory, the site loads properly. If I remove the proxy, it still gives me the same error.
Edit: I got the proxies to work with an extension, but the requests are not showing up. It stays empty even after visiting multiple pages.
